# How to hide hidden files in AEM CRXDE Lite

Tags: aem

The question is basically the title of the post.

Is there a possibility to hide the hidden files that appear on the CRXDE Lite?

I have a mac and in my CRXDE Lite i can see the `.DS_Store` files and i don't want to see them.

Answer (score 0):

Why hide them when you can delete them? This simple example is a Servlet. you could run this nightly with an [OSGi scheduler](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/scheduler-service-commons-scheduler.html).

```
package com.foo.bar;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;

import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@SlingServlet(paths={"/bin/deletedsstore"})
public class DeleteDSStoreServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DeleteDSStoreServlet.class);

    private static final String SQL2_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/content]) and NAME() = '.DS_Store'";
    private static final int SAVE_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ResourceResolver resolver = request.getResourceResolver();
        Iterator<Resource> resources = resolver.findResources(SQL2_QUERY, Query.JCR_SQL2);

        int deleted = 0;

        while (resources.hasNext()) {
            Resource resource = resources.next();
            String path = resource.getPath();

            resolver.delete(resource);
            log.info("Deleted node: " + path);

            deleted++;

            if (deleted % SAVE_THRESHOLD == 0) {
                resolver.commit();
            }
        }

        if (resolver.hasChanges()) {
            resolver.commit();
        }

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("Deleted " + deleted + " .DS_Store nodes");
    }
}
```